# Collapse in Bootstrap 5 not working when I click on the toggle button

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

Collapse is not working when I click on the toggle button. Here's my code. What changes do I need to make to get this working?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <title>Project Prototype</title>
   </head>
   <body>

<div class="collapse" id="navbarToggleExternalContent">
  <div class="bg-dark p-4">
    <h5 class="text-white h4">About</h5>
    <p class="text-muted">Toggleable via the navbar brand.</p>
  </div>
</div>
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
      <img src="movie-cinema-svgrepo-com.svg" alt="" width="30" height="24" class="d-inline-block align-text-top">
      Project
    </a>

    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarToggleExternalContent" aria-controls="navbarToggleExternalContent" aria-expanded="true" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

  </div>
</nav>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add Bootstrap JavaScript bundle.

Place the following `<script>` near the end of your pages, right before the closing `</body>` tag.

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
JavaScript bootstrap plugin missing in your code. You've to include both the plugins and dependency,bootstrap.bundle.js and bootstrap.bundle.min.js.
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

**Just add the above script☝️**